# Core Data and version control: Wat is the best strategies to commit versions of the (development) persistent store?

Tags: git, macos, svn, core-data, version-control

I'm working on a Core Data app, under Git version control (actually, I switched from Subversion to Git a few weeks ago). Two days ago I noticed that an interface element was no longer responding properly, so I rolled back to a revision four or five days ago. Problem was, I couldn't run the app to check the behavior of the problematic UI, because the persistent store (a sqlite database) was no longer compatible with the dataModel.

The changes to the dataModel were minor enough that they'd been taking care of by Core Data's lightweight migration, but big enough to block me. Of course, I could fix this, but it would take me an hour or so when all I wanted to was quickly check how a minor element responded to a particular event.

So that made me think: how could I add the persistent store to my versioning workflow? I'm talking here about a database used in development, not even half a Megabyte in size. NSPersistentContainer by default creates them at ~/Library/MyProjectName/MyDataModelName.sqlite, which is outside the source tree. I'd have no problem with manually copying the versioned database to the default location in case of a rollback.

Comment: One possible strategy is that the creation scripts of the database are stored in the same repository. That way you can easily use the database of your needs at all times.

Comment: Keep the recipe but not the cake, right? Yes, good point, and I thought I had that covered but Core Data's lightweight migration tripped me up. In the good old days Core Data wouldn't let the minutest change to the data model go unpunished. These days, one can add and remove attributes, change numbers to scalar, turn transient on and off in blissful peace -- but you pay the price at rollback time.

Comment: @ElisevanLooij version control database dump is a better way and it won't make git repo size sharply increase.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I've added a 'Run Script' Build Phase with the following script:

```
cp  ~/Library/Application\ Support/$PROJECT_NAME/*.sqlite DB_Archive
```

DB_Archive is a folder I've created inside the Xcode project folder. Because the project is under Git control, DB_Archive immediately showed up when I did a commit. Under Subversion, one would have to import the folder (or create it on the server), then update.

The advantage of the 'Run Script' Build Phase it allows me to use the PROJECT_NAME environment variable.  I've also tried running the script as post-action in a scheme, but there PROJECT_NAME was not recognized. I will have to remember to add the script to each new project, of course, unless I want to invest time in modifying some Xcode templates.